# Uploadify always freeze my Firefox

Tags: firefox, uploadify

I got the error on Uploadify - onQueueFull event. You can test [here](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/events/onqueuefull/).
I already test the several in my Firefox(3.6.13).That's not working only on firefox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when alert message appears if you do not close it and open a new tab or somehow switch to different (because alert is modal), Firefox freezes.

My FF also got frozen after several times.

http://pokit.etf.ba/get/5e4bb9d6b9c3bc6b1bd1128c1342eb74.png

plugin-container.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I may be need to check and upgrade my flashplayer on firefox ?